# IOS 11 Safari remember Camera Permission

Tags: web, browser, safari, webrtc, ios11

My problem is that I have a Web App which uses the camera, but everytime you load the Page and call the camera function it asks for permission.

Is there a way to save the Camera permission for a site? (Like Chrome on Android (asks you once for a site))
Or does somebody know when the webrtc is avaiable for Chrome on IOS?

Comment: Are you accessing your web app via a shortcut on the home screen?

Comment: No, would it change something?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49942017/426790 -- it seems like there is no way to permanently grant camera access yet!

Comment: Can you share some functional code for this? I'm on ios 11.4 on an iphone x and no webrtc demo in mobile safari is working on my end :(

Comment: take a look at this
https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/getusermedia/gum

Comment: This is now possible - see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368061/5740181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible with IOS 13 and iPadOS 13 to save permission settings in Safari.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

To answer my own question, I found these links helpful.  

https://www.apple.com/au/ios/ios-13/features/  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368061/3204185

Comment: This answer shows you how to activate this setting https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368061/5740181