# In iOS Safari, permissions from getUserMedia time out in a minute

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, getusermedia

Our website does a series of timed actions that culminate in the user recording something with their microphone. Because we don't want to interrupt the process with the browser's "our-domain.com would like to access the microphone [cancel] [allow]" message, we start with a `getUserMedia` call so the pop up happens when the user first clicks "start".

That all works fine in most browsers and devices. However, on Safari on iOS, there appears to be a time out. If the series of actions before the website starts recording is short (like 30 seconds), everything works. However, if the series of actions is a little longer (like 90 seconds), the permission dialog pops up again.

I have two questions:

1) Is this behavior documented anywhere? I can't seem to find anything about it. Is there a set timeout or are devices free to set their own timeout?

2) Do you have any suggestions about how to handle this case? The two things that occur to me are

a) to ping `getUserMedia` every 20 seconds to keep it from timing out or

b) just start recording at the beginning of the process but only start saving the recording when we are ready for it.

The problem with the first solution is that some browsers have a "remember this decision" checkbox and if that is not checked, this will cause the popup every time I ping.

The problem with the second solution is that when recording starts the red microphone appears in the browser so the user thinks we've started recording.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I'm running into a similar issue, although in my case I'm playing media in the background, which hangs if I ping getUserMedia.

Comment: I did option "b" - start recording right after the user approves it, but only start capturing it when the user clicks "record". Not ideal, but the problem will eventually go away when all those old iphones slow down too much.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on iOS 12.
Apparently Safari on iOS 13 can remember and allow users to control the permission settings per website.

Take a look at this comment:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368061/9522511

On Apple's official website:
https://www.apple.com/au/ios/ios-13/features/
Safari -> Per-site settings

If updating OS didn't suit your case, what about doing option a) only on Safari?