# iOS Browsers except Safari Keeps asking camera permission every time I load the page

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, qr-code

We are currently developing a qr code scanning system using laravel but when I test it on Chrome or other browser except Safari, it always ask camera permission.

I have already allow camera permission on browser setting on my iPad. Is there other way to permanently allow it or only ask once on Chrome browser like on android that remembers my choice? Or is it possible to do it programmatically like using Javascript?

thank you so much! I really need everyone's help, I couldn't find any related topics on the internet about this

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for the PWA's to change it from "Ask" to "Allow". There is an issue on WebKit around this: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215884, but what can you do is to change it manually in browser settings, as it was mentioned: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368061/615393.